# how to count the specific word inputted in STDIN inside the text (PERL)

Tags: perl

how to count the specific word inputted in STDIN inside the text (PERL)
my output just count all the owrds found inside the text . but i need the specific word i inputted inside the STDIN

```
open my($file), '<','C:\Users\yukari\Desktop\hi.txt' or die "not exist";

print "Search the word:";
$word = <STDIN>;

print "\n";

while ( my $line = <$file> ) {
    chomp($line);

    # print $line; 

    foreach $word (split(' ', $line)) {
        $count{$word}++;
    }
}

foreach $word (sort keys %count) {
    print "$word: $count{$word}\n";
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include your _hi.txt_ file. Also make sure your code always uses `use strict` and `use warnings`.

Comment: I've edited your question to improve the formatting of the code. You're welcome, but please do it yourself in future. If you are asking a large number of people to read and understand your code, then it is only polite to make that as easy for them as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to get a word from the user and count the number of occurrences of that word in the entire text file.

You can try something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(WRITE,'>','log.txt') or die "Unable to open the file";
my $string = <<END;
foo baz bar
baz bar bar foo
foo foo bar bar baz baz
baz baz baz
END

print WRITE $string;
close WRITE;

open(READ, '<','log.txt') or die "unable to open the file";

my $search = <STDIN>;
chomp $search;
my $count = 0;

while ( my $line = <READ> ) {
    chomp($line);
    my @words = split(' ',$line);
    foreach my $word(@words){
        $count++ if($word eq $search);
    }
}
close READ;
print "Search string: $search, Count: $count","\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem here. You are using the variable `$word` for three different things.

You are using it as the word that you are searching for:

```
$word = <STDIN>;
```

You are using it to store each word on a line read from your file:

```
foreach $word (split(' ', $line)) {
```

And you are using it to contain the keys you are reading from your hash at the end.

```
foreach $word (sort keys %count) {
```

In particular, the second use is interfering with the first. When you are reading data from your file, you have no way of knowing what word you are looking for.

If you are looking for a single word, there is no need for a hash to store the counts. I'd write your code like this:

```
# ALWAYS INCLUDE THESE
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

# Renamed your variable, it's a file handle, not a file.
# Also, include $! in error message so we know what really
# went wrong.
open my $fh, '<', 'C:\Users\yukari\Desktop\hi.txt'
    or die "Can't open file: $!";

print "Search the word:";
my $search_word = <STDIN>;

print "\n";

# Scalar variable to store the count
my $count;

# Remove the $line variable and use Perl's default variable $_
# instead. This makes the code *far* cleaner.
while ( <$file> ) {
    chomp;

    # By default, split splits $_ on whitespace
    foreach $word (split) {
        # Skip words we don't care about
        next if $word ne $search_word;
        # Increment the counter
        $count++;
    }
}

say "$search_word appeared $word times";
```